# Navigate outside router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have followed the official documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

But when I want to navigate to LoginComponent inside the AuthGuard, I do not want to navigate inside the parent component (AppComponent) that holds router-outlet tag. I want to redirect the LoginComponent outside the parent component(AppComponent) that has router-outlet tag. As a single, stand-alone component LoginComponent, I do not want that the LoginComponent has the master html of the AppComponent.

Is this possible? how?
**Full example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/34ajPEi1OucEXNw4L2Do?p=preview

**Update:**
Also when I tried in the AppComponent.html to condition the router-outlet as the following:

```
<div *ngIf="isAuth()">
<h1 class="title">Head Router</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isAuth()"><app-login></app-login></div>
```

on the console I get the following error:

```
browser_adapter.ts:82EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'
```

**full error example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rEEZrB?p=preview

Comment: What you are doing is not clear through this code.

Comment: Please add more context, ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce. I'm not able to make sens of your prose description.

Comment: I have updated the questions with the two examples

Comment: You're placing `router-outlet` inside `ngIf` directive and condition of ngIf equals `false` so your view doesn't have `router-outlet`

Comment: @yurzi if u are talking in the second example, is the idea. Put the login outside the router-outlet when is not logged in. I think I don't fully understand what u mean

Comment: @yurzui also check the error I have in the console in the second example, that I mentioned

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tLBpVH?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Ah! is a solution, I would have prefer to navigate to a standalone component. But is just hide the the code that you cannot access if u are not loggedin. And just left the router-outlet alone there. Thanks, is a practical solution! I will wait is someone knows how to redirect to a standalone componet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is not possible. I think you would need to create another master html file and bootstrap your standalone component there. Then navigate to the url of this new file. 
Another option would be hiding the unwanted nodes (using `*ngClass='{"hidden":is_login}'` ) or something similar in your main component.